# How to shift a whole build WITHOUT MCEdit

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am building an adventure map, and want a house to move away from the player as soon as he/she moves towards it.

An obvious way to do it is to /setblock each and every block, but that would require hundreds of command blocks. So is there any short idea of moving the build?

Comment: Why can't you use mcedit?

Comment: "I am building an adventure map" so, it must be continuous. Like you are moving towards your house, but it moves away from you. MCEDIT is third party and does not offer vanilla integration. @aman207

Comment: Maybe you could create some copies of the house some distance from each other, that are altered individually to show the stages of moving backwards, then when the player comes near the house, have them teleport to the next stage?

Comment: @tuxedoandex Thank you for an idea that you just gave me! Rather than teleporting the whole build, I have can much better idea.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the /clone command to move medium sized builds to where ever you want. Here's a vid:

Answer (score 0):

If you just make a facade of the house, rather than an actual building, you might be able to accomplish this with some combination of pistons and slime blocks.  There's a hard upper limit of 12 blocks per piston, though, so it would probably need to be a very simplistic house (or a very elaborate piston train).  If you can keep the player far enough away, this could still work.  Of course, if you plan on later allowing the player to visit the house, this won't do at all.  In that case, you might consider splitting your adventure into "chapters" (multiple separate maps which are intended to be played in some order).  That way, you could have the unreachable facade in chapter 1 and a real house in chapter 2.

Alternatively, you could move the player.  If the landscape is sufficiently boring or repetitive, the player might not notice that you're teleporting them through the same terrain.  Or they would, but they'd accept it as part of the fiction.  You can use a scoreboard to track how far they've "traveled" and use teleporting to loop the terrain.

If you really want to stick with vanilla, these sorts of effects may be difficult to accomplish in the general case.  If you just want to deny access to the building, you could put it on the wrong side of a chasm or other natural barrier.  This has the added benefit of providing an affordance - a logical way to overcome the barrier (e.g. if there's a chasm, the player will probably start thinking about [bridges](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BrokenBridge)), which can turn into a plot hook or whatever else you need.

Comment: It was not that I never thought of it, I implemented the facade idea already, but since I want the player to eventually enter, and the house to move only on player stimulus, the piston mech was rendered useless. I think I'll have to do it the hard way.

Comment: It is actually a limit of 14 blocks per piston.

Comment: You may want to look at the "Commands" page of Gamepedia, @Kevin. You'll learn a lot.

Comment: @FungusKing: You might read the dates on posts before you accuse the author of ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

Since I need to teleport the facade back, everytime the player moves towards it, what I will do is, create multiple facades one behind the other, and exactly overlapping each other.

Then when the player moves towards that facade, I'll use

```
/fill
```

Command to simply fill that facade with air, and thus it would appear that the build has shifted backward. We'll use the trick of illusion here.

Comment: You can click the green check mark to select this as being the final answer.

Answer (score -2):

MCEDIT would be simpler but there is a solution using a plugin called"WorldEdit"

All you would need to do it start a bukkit server (hard now a days but give it a shot) download the plugin, move the world over and check out some tutorials on how to do what you want with it.

Comment: Oh, as I said I am making an adventure map, so everything needs to be vanilla. No plugins.

Comment: Worldedit is a terrain editor In game it does not add or remove content. All you would have to do is delete the plugin/ server after moving your world when your done and nothing would have changed

Comment: Again, I do not want the build to shift by my stimulus. I want it to shift in real time, when the actual player is moving. Check out my comment on the question post. Therefore plugins are a no no.

Comment: Well other than that command block coding is your best bet

Comment: I know that. But is there any shorter way to do it. Like a smaller code. I am thinking of setblocking every block.

Comment: I suppose you could use command blocks to place command blocks, but [that probably won't end well](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8gOh0wEgLg).

Comment: You could look into a Youtuber named "SethBling" who uses commands blocks and understands them almost like an expert his videos could be of hep to you